# Possiblility to receive event hub events in batch using azure event hub triggered functions

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub

I am sending 2000 ingress events as a batch to an event hub. And I am looking to consume egress by azure functions[evnt hub triggered functions].

Is there any possibility to send event hub events as a batch in azure event hub triggered functions?

Or it will run every event for the event hub?

The no. of executions get cost, so only am looking fewer executions.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Azure Functions support batches with Event Hub trigger. [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-event-hubs) have this example:

```cs
[FunctionName("EventHubTriggerCSharp")]
public static void Run(
    [EventHubTrigger("samples-workitems", Connection = "EventHubConnectionAppSetting")] 
    string[] eventHubMessages, 
    TraceWriter log)
{
    foreach (var message in eventHubMessages)
    {
        log.Info($"C# Event Hub trigger function processed a message: {message}");
    }
}
```

You could use `EventData[]` instead of `string[]` too.

Comment: EventData[]  - processing array of events. My events are not as array events.Those are indivudual events.

Comment: @PonmaniChinnaswamy There is no such distinction. Function will be executed for an array of individual events. The only link between those events is that they are from the same partition.

Comment: If the same partition of events are executed in array means how i will find the no of executions ?  I need to calculate the cost for no of executions. Is there any limit for events in an array?  how it will take?

Comment: @PonmaniChinnaswamy You can't calculate the cost reliably in advance, also because cost is mostly defined by RAM consumption and duration. Just run a test and measure. Batching will save a lot in most cases.

Comment: Thanks @Mikhail. i will test and measure